# MSBuild 15 csproj with NuSpecFile

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, csproj, msbuild-15

We are working to migrate to PackageReference restore style csproj's but have many nuspec's for such projects the rely on some of the default nuget pack CLI behavior. Specifically:

- version substitution
- auto-generation of dependencies section
- auto generation of files section

Essentially, I am looking to run dotnet pack on a csproj and have it use the csproj to generate the files, dependencies and version, but an existing nuspec file for the rest of the metadata.

If I specify NuSpecFile in the csproj, it correctly uses the nuspec file, but no longer generates the files, dependencies, or version based on the csproj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSBuild based packing functionality of the .NET SDK has the option to either generate a nuspec file to use for packing (default) or use a user-supplied nuspec file (`NuSpecFile` property) for generating the package.

There is no functionality to mix these approaches.

I suggest putting all the metadata you need into the csproj file. See the [documentation on the pack target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target) for the list of MSBuild properties that can be used to control the package metadata.

If you are looking to share metadata across multiple projects, create a `Directory.Build.props` file at the root folder of your solution (directory hierarchy at or above all projects) with the contents you want to share:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Authors>shared authors value</Authors>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://something</PackageProjectUrl>
    …
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Oh well...was just looking for an easier way of migrating to the new build system. I wish msbuild weren’t such a mess.